# Add elements in xts

Tags: r, xts

I'm in the process of converting my script to use `xts` rather than a data frame, but getting stuck with doing calculations across elements in different rows / columns.

In reality I'm iterating through the df rows using a for loop, and using if-elses based on the calculation.

But, to simplify the problem, I can add say Col A Row 1 with Col B Row 2 just fine in a df, but not in an xts.... here's some example code:

```
> df <- data.frame(c(1:3),c(4:6))
> names(df) <- c('colA','colB')
> df
  colA colB
1    1    4
2    2    5
3    3    6
> df$colA[1] + df$colB[2]
[1] 6
> 
> 
> library(xts)
> x <- xts(df, order.by=as.Date(1:3))
> x
           colA colB
1970-01-02    1    4
1970-01-03    2    5
1970-01-04    3    6
> x$colA[1] + x$colB[2]
Data:
integer(0)

Index:
numeric(0)
>
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two xts objects are added they are merged to align the times and then added.  Row 1 and Row 2 have no common indexes so the merge produces an empty object.

Here are some alternatives:

**1) [[** A single `[` will return another xts object but `[[` will not thereby avoiding the problem:

```
x$colA[[1]] + x$colB[[2]]
## [1] 6
```

**2) coredata**  Try explicitly converting to ordinary vectors before adding:

```
coredata(x$colA)[1] + coredata(x$colB)[2]
## [1] 6
```

**3) c** Here we concantenate the two values into a new xts object and then sum the values in that new object.

```
sum(c(x$colA[1], x$colB[2]))
## [1] 6
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks so much for the answers and explanations. Cheers, simmo.

Comment: @simmo: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).